# PHP Regex - Match only a word, or a hyphenated word

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_match for form validation. The Regex needs to match any input that doesn't contain only characters, and characters followed by a hyphen also followed by more characters.

In other words the regex should catch any input that isn't a word made up of characters [a-z] and a hyphenated word (where there exists only one hyphen in the middle).

The regex should also catch words with a trailing hyphen (without another word following the hyphen e.g. "hello-") and should also catch words with a starting hyphen (e.g. "-hello").

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code - if I understand your question, this will match only `john-smith`, which is what you want. Note - this is almost exactly what @Wrikken proposed in an earlier comment.

```
<?php
$test = array("john-smith", "123john", "john-", "john and mary smith");
$regex = '/^([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?)$/i';
foreach($test as $t) {
  if(preg_match($regex, $t, $m)) {
    echo "$t matches!\n";
  }
}
?>
```

See demo at

http://regex101.com/r/aU3qM0